# Unable to link the 64bit ftd2xx static library with project dispaying linker error. How to link the ftd2xx 64bit library to the code

Tags: codeblocks, d2xx

I'm trying to link the ftd2xx.lib (amd64 https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/CDM/CDM%20v2.12.28%20WHQL%20Certified.zip) static file to my test program in codeblocks. I'm running codeblocks(mingw) on a intel i3-7020, x64 based processor. I'm getting the linker error obj\Debug\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `_imp__FT_ListDevices@12'. Can someone please tell me how to link the static library of ftd2xx.lib 64bit version in codeblocks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ftd2xx.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FT_STATUS ftStatus;
    int numDevs;
    ftStatus = FT_ListDevices(&numDevs,NULL,FT_LIST_NUMBER_ONLY);
    cout<<numDevs<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It is supposed to compile successfully and display the number of devices connected.

Comment: Are you on Windows? Haveyou  added the library path to the project options linker settings?

Comment: Yes. The ftd2xx.lib file has been added to the linker settings. I'm currently using windows 10 Home edition.